Lilypond - Lyrics In Context With Multiple Verses
In the manual, at https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/techniques-specific-to-lyrics#working-with-lyrics-and-variables, it describes

For different or more complex orderings, the best way is to define the music and lyric variables first,... and then add the lyrics using \context underneath.

This works great to keep maximum control over lyric positioning, but later:

When the words to a repeated volta section are different, the words to each repeat must be entered in separate Lyrics contexts...

the manual uses a different technique (lyrics specified inline). How do we combine the two techniques: words for each repeat in separate Lyrics contexts and adding lyrics using the \context underneath?
For an example:
\version "2.24.3"
lyricschorus=\lyricmode{Get in here now}
lyricsvone=\lyricmode{I'll get the broom}
lyricsvtwo=\lyricmode{I'll hose you down}
voicechorus={a4 b c' d'}
voiceverse={\repeat volta 2 {b c' d' e'}}
voicemusic={
    \voicechorus
        \addlyrics{\lyricschorus}
    \voiceverse
        \addlyrics{\lyricsvone}
        \addlyrics{\lyricsvtwo}
}
\score {
    \new StaffGroup <<
        \new Staff \voicemusic
    >>
}

which yields:

How can we write this example with separate \context sections? (In case it is important, the approach should also work with accompanying instruments, too.)

Here's a template of how I would do what you want:
\version "2.24.3"


theNotes = \relative {
 a'4 a a a
 \repeat volta 2 { b4 b b b }
}

nonRepeated = \lyricmode { Not re -- peat -- ed. }
firstTime = \lyricmode { The first time words. }
secondTime = \lyricmode { Sec -- ond time words. }

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff {
      \new Voice = "melody" {
        \theNotes
      }
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" {
      \nonRepeated
      <<
        \firstTime
        \new Lyrics {
          \set associatedVoice = "melody"
          \secondTime
        }
      >>
    }
  >>
}


I think this doesn't answer the question: "How do we combine the two techniques: words for each repeat in separate Lyrics contexts and adding lyrics using the \context underneath?" Your answer doesn't use \context like in the lilypond document where it says, "...and then add the lyrics using \context underneath."
